# Adding an obvious (custom) button to UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would simply like to add the obvious button "Open in Safari"
How can I do it in a simple way.

```
#pragma mark - Share the link
- (IBAction)activityButtonPressed:(id)sender {


    NSString *textToShare = @"I just shared this from my App";
   // UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textToShare, urlToShare,nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:Nil];
    //This is an array of excluded activities to appear on the UIActivityViewController
    //activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];


}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As nevo shalev said you need to subclass [UIActivity class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here is an example:

UrlActivity.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UrlActivity : UIActivity

@end
```

UrlActivity.m:

```
#import "UrlActivity.h"

@implementation UrlActivity

- (NSString *)activityType
{
    return @"your Custom Type";
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle
{
    return @"Title to display under your icon";
}

- (UIImage *)activityImage
{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"your icon.png"];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    // basically in your case: return YES if activity items are urls  
}

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    //open safari with urls (activityItems)
}

+(UIActivityCategory)activityCategory
{
    return UIActivityCategoryShare; // says that your icon will belong in application group, not in the lower part;
}

@end
```

And in your main file (after importing UrlActivity.h):

```
#pragma mark - Share the link
- (IBAction)activityButtonPressed:(id)sender {


    NSString *textToShare = @"I just shared this from my App";
   // UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textToShare, urlToShare,nil];

    // create an array with your custom activity and add it to the activityVC
    NSArray *appActivities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UrlActivity alloc] init]]];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:appActivities];
    //This is an array of excluded activities to appear on the UIActivityViewController
    //activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];


}
```

Comment: Small correction:

`NSArray *appActivities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UrlActivity alloc] init]]];`

needs to be 

`NSArray *appActivities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[MobrActivityView alloc] init], nil];`

Answer (score 3):

This project does it for you: https://github.com/davbeck/TUSafariActivity and it supports CocoaPods

Answer (score 0):

you need to subclass UIActivity and and implement the methods and after add the class to applicationActivities

Answer (score -6):

```
#pragma mark - Share the link
- (IBAction)activityButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: urlToShare];
}
```

Comment: That will not add a share button, I would like to have all the sharing options activityView gives + open in safari

Comment: It also doesn't hurt to [google around](https://github.com/davbeck/TUSafariActivity) and [around](http://uiactivities.com/)